# Customization of Wacom tablet buttons

Tags: wacom

I am using Wacom Intuos M, together with Sketchbook, to give online math lectures.

In order to be faster, and for the screen to be cleaner, I'd like to use just the 4 tablet buttons to change the brush color (pen, in my case). Just to be clear: I'd like the first button to change the color to yellow, the second to change the color to blue, the third to red, and the fourth to black.

Can I manage to do this?

If yes, could someone give me a detailed and step-by step answer?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this is possible in general. The function buttons are more like F-keys... they are designed to perform some global operation, not alter a specific in-application tool. So, one would need to utilize more global application features in order to swap a color.

If you could assign a shortcut *within the application* you are using for a color, then the tablet function buttons could merely call that shortcut. I do *not* know Sketch, but in my experience it's not possible to set a shortcut for merely a color in *any* application.

Another *possible* way would be a script (action/macro) that sets the brush color to something specific. Then a shortcut to call that script, and assign that shortcut to tablet functions.

In Illustrator, one could use Tool Presets with a shortcut, or an action with an assigned shortcut, and then assign the shortcut to the tablet buttons. I don't know if this is possible via Sketch.